# Problem with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 different class... de first one (MainSoup) is the main class and this class extends activity.
The second class (View2) extends View.
in View2 class is where i make my OnTouchEvent and my Canvas... 
I also have a frameLayout with 2 layout... in the first one i put multiple textViews.
On top of this first layout i put the second one wich has nothing and here is where i draw with my Canvas and touch events. At this point everythings works just fine.

The problems begin when i want to make an intent... I put the intent in de Main class (MainSoup):
          Intent i = new Intent(this, org.me.androidsoup.MainSoup.class);
          startActivity(i);
 but i dont know how to trigger it (since the OnTouchEvent is in the View2 class).

And if i try to put it in the View2 class, i have troubles with the startActivity line, It doesnt recognize it and tells me to create a method call startActivity.

Comment: If youj're inside the onTouchEvent() method just use `this.getContext().startActivity(...)`

Answer (score 3):

startActivity() is a method that requires a context (it's actually a method defined by the Context class).
Views have a method called getContext() that will return the context attached to that view. You could use that for invoking the Intent.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thinks briefly about it gave me 3 options:

1. You take care of the onTouchEvent on the Activity, (you do findViewById and set the onTouchEvent to it, then you have context)
2. You add a static Context variable to the Application Class, when each activity starts (**onCreate**) it sets the Contexts as this like:

   Application.context = this;
3. Use the getContext() method on the View to get the Context, and do new Intent(getContext, ActivityYouWant.class);

I think the first and third are the most valid options. But you choose.